# Getting lots of linker errors when changed the Qt projects Build directory

Tags: c++, qt, linker-errors, qcustomplot

I am new to Qt, I created a GUI application in Qt and everything was fine, until I changed the Build directory from Projects section in `QtCreator`. Now I get many linker errors which I am clueless on how to resolve them.

I tried reverting back to the previous build folder, but it failed again. I do clean the project and do a rebuild each time, yet nothing works. Here is a list of those linker errors I'm getting:

```
    11:50:08: Running steps for project Ann_network...
11:50:08: Configuration unchanged, skipping qmake step.
11:50:08: Starting: "L:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" 
    L:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug
    link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /DEBUG /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:debug\Ann_network.exe @C:\Users\Master\AppData\Local\Temp\Ann_network.exe.7864.15.jom
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPAxis::setRange(double,double)" (?setRange@QCPAxis@@QEAAXNN@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::Init(void)" (?Init@MainWindow@@AEAAXXZ)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPAxis::setLabel(class QString const &)" (?setLabel@QCPAxis@@QEAAXAEBVQString@@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::Init(void)" (?Init@MainWindow@@AEAAXXZ)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPAxis::setLabel(class QString const &)" (?setLabel@QCPAxis@@QEAAXAEBVQString@@@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl QCustomPlot::QCustomPlot(class QWidget *)" (??0QCustomPlot@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl Ui_MainWindow::setupUi(class QMainWindow *)" (?setupUi@Ui_MainWindow@@QEAAXPEAVQMainWindow@@@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class QCPGraph * __cdecl QCustomPlot::graph(int)const " (?graph@QCustomPlot@@QEBAPEAVQCPGraph@@H@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::XORNet(bool)" (?XORNet@MainWindow@@AEAAX_N@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class QCPGraph * __cdecl QCustomPlot::addGraph(class QCPAxis *,class QCPAxis *)" (?addGraph@QCustomPlot@@QEAAPEAVQCPGraph@@PEAVQCPAxis@@0@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::Init(void)" (?Init@MainWindow@@AEAAXXZ)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCustomPlot::replot(enum QCustomPlot::RefreshPriority)" (?replot@QCustomPlot@@QEAAXW4RefreshPriority@1@@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::XORNet(bool)" (?XORNet@MainWindow@@AEAAX_N@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCustomPlot::replot(enum QCustomPlot::RefreshPriority)" (?replot@QCustomPlot@@QEAAXW4RefreshPriority@1@@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPGraph::setData(class QVector<double> const &,class QVector<double> const &)" (?setData@QCPGraph@@QEAAXAEBV?$QVector@N@@0@Z) referenced in function "private: void __cdecl MainWindow::XORNet(bool)" (?XORNet@MainWindow@@AEAAX_N@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPLayer::setVisible(bool)" (?setVisible@QCPLayer@@QEAAX_N@Z) referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl QCPLayer::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@QCPLayer@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPLayerable::setVisible(bool)" (?setVisible@QCPLayerable@@QEAAX_N@Z) referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl QCPLayerable::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@QCPLayerable@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: bool __cdecl QCPLayerable::setLayer(class QCPLayer *)" (?setLayer@QCPLayerable@@QEAA_NPEAVQCPLayer@@@Z) referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl QCPLayerable::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@QCPLayerable@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPLayerable::setAntialiased(bool)" (?setAntialiased@QCPLayerable@@QEAAX_N@Z) referenced in function "private: static void __cdecl QCPLayerable::qt_static_metacall(class QObject *,enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_static_metacall@QCPLayerable@@CAXPEAVQObject@@W4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPLayoutElement::setOuterRect(class QRect const &)" (?setOuterRect@QCPLayoutElement@@QEAAXAEBVQRect@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPLayoutElement::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPLayoutElement@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPLayoutElement::setMargins(class QMargins const &)" (?setMargins@QCPLayoutElement@@QEAAXAEBVQMargins@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPLayoutElement::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPLayoutElement@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPLayoutElement::setMinimumMargins(class QMargins const &)" (?setMinimumMargins@QCPLayoutElement@@QEAAXAEBVQMargins@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPLayoutElement::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPLayoutElement@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPLayoutElement::setMinimumSize(class QSize const &)" (?setMinimumSize@QCPLayoutElement@@QEAAXAEBVQSize@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPLayoutElement::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPLayoutElement@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPLayoutElement::setMaximumSize(class QSize const &)" (?setMaximumSize@QCPLayoutElement@@QEAAXAEBVQSize@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPLayoutElement::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPLayoutElement@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl QCPLayoutGrid::rowCount(void)const " (?rowCount@QCPLayoutGrid@@QEBAHXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPLayoutGrid::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPLayoutGrid@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl QCPLayoutGrid::columnCount(void)const " (?columnCount@QCPLayoutGrid@@QEBAHXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPLayoutGrid::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPLayoutGrid@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPLayoutGrid::setColumnStretchFactors(class QList<double> const &)" (?setColumnStretchFactors@QCPLayoutGrid@@QEAAXAEBV?$QList@N@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPLayoutGrid::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPLayoutGrid@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPLayoutGrid::setRowStretchFactors(class QList<double> const &)" (?setRowStretchFactors@QCPLayoutGrid@@QEAAXAEBV?$QList@N@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPLayoutGrid::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPLayoutGrid@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPLayoutGrid::setColumnSpacing(int)" (?setColumnSpacing@QCPLayoutGrid@@QEAAXH@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPLayoutGrid::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPLayoutGrid@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPLayoutGrid::setRowSpacing(int)" (?setRowSpacing@QCPLayoutGrid@@QEAAXH@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPLayoutGrid::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPLayoutGrid@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPGrid::setSubGridVisible(bool)" (?setSubGridVisible@QCPGrid@@QEAAX_N@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPGrid::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPGrid@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPGrid::setAntialiasedSubGrid(bool)" (?setAntialiasedSubGrid@QCPGrid@@QEAAX_N@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPGrid::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPGrid@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPGrid::setAntialiasedZeroLine(bool)" (?setAntialiasedZeroLine@QCPGrid@@QEAAX_N@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPGrid::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPGrid@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPGrid::setPen(class QPen const &)" (?setPen@QCPGrid@@QEAAXAEBVQPen@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPGrid::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPGrid@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPGrid::setSubGridPen(class QPen const &)" (?setSubGridPen@QCPGrid@@QEAAXAEBVQPen@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPGrid::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPGrid@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPGrid::setZeroLinePen(class QPen const &)" (?setZeroLinePen@QCPGrid@@QEAAXAEBVQPen@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPGrid::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPGrid@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl QCPAxis::tickLabelPadding(void)const " (?tickLabelPadding@QCPAxis@@QEBAHXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: double __cdecl QCPAxis::tickLabelRotation(void)const " (?tickLabelRotation@QCPAxis@@QEBANXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: enum QCPAxis::LabelSide __cdecl QCPAxis::tickLabelSide(void)const " (?tickLabelSide@QCPAxis@@QEBA?AW4LabelSide@1@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class QString __cdecl QCPAxis::numberFormat(void)const " (?numberFormat@QCPAxis@@QEBA?AVQString@@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl QCPAxis::tickLengthIn(void)const " (?tickLengthIn@QCPAxis@@QEBAHXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl QCPAxis::tickLengthOut(void)const " (?tickLengthOut@QCPAxis@@QEBAHXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl QCPAxis::subTickLengthIn(void)const " (?subTickLengthIn@QCPAxis@@QEBAHXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl QCPAxis::subTickLengthOut(void)const " (?subTickLengthOut@QCPAxis@@QEBAHXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl QCPAxis::labelPadding(void)const " (?labelPadding@QCPAxis@@QEBAHXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: int __cdecl QCPAxis::offset(void)const " (?offset@QCPAxis@@QEBAHXZ) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class QCPLineEnding __cdecl QCPAxis::lowerEnding(void)const " (?lowerEnding@QCPAxis@@QEBA?AVQCPLineEnding@@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: class QCPLineEnding __cdecl QCPAxis::upperEnding(void)const " (?upperEnding@QCPAxis@@QEBA?AVQCPLineEnding@@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPAxis::setScaleType(enum QCPAxis::ScaleType)" (?setScaleType@QCPAxis@@QEAAXW4ScaleType@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPAxis::setScaleLogBase(double)" (?setScaleLogBase@QCPAxis@@QEAAXN@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPAxis::setRange(class QCPRange const &)" (?setRange@QCPAxis@@QEAAXAEBVQCPRange@@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPAxis::setRangeReversed(bool)" (?setRangeReversed@QCPAxis@@QEAAX_N@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPAxis::setAutoTicks(bool)" (?setAutoTicks@QCPAxis@@QEAAX_N@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPAxis::setAutoTickCount(int)" (?setAutoTickCount@QCPAxis@@QEAAXH@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPAxis::setAutoTickLabels(bool)" (?setAutoTickLabels@QCPAxis@@QEAAX_N@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPAxis::setAutoTickStep(bool)" (?setAutoTickStep@QCPAxis@@QEAAX_N@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPAxis::setAutoSubTicks(bool)" (?setAutoSubTicks@QCPAxis@@QEAAX_N@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPAxis::setTicks(bool)" (?setTicks@QCPAxis@@QEAAX_N@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPAxis::setTickLabels(bool)" (?setTickLabels@QCPAxis@@QEAAX_N@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPAxis::setTickLabelPadding(int)" (?setTickLabelPadding@QCPAxis@@QEAAXH@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAxis@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPAxis::setTickLabelType(enum QCPAxis::LabelType)" (?setTickLabelType@QCPAxis@@QEAAXW4LabelType@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: virtual int __cdecl QCPAxis::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@QCPAbstractPlottable@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
moc_qcustomplot.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl QCPAbstractPlottable::setValueAxis(class QCPAxis *)" (?setValueAxis@QCPAbstractPlottable@@QEAAXPEAVQCPAxis@@@Z) referenced in 

\Ann_network\bin\Makefile [debug] Error 2
    11:50:09: The process "L:\Qt\Qt5.5.0\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
    Error while building/deploying project Ann_network (kit: Desktop Qt 5.5.0 MSVC2013 64bit)
    When executing step "Make"
    11:50:09: Elapsed time: 00:01.
```

Note : 
this is how my .pro file looks like :

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-09-18T10:56:00
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets printsupport

TARGET = Ann_network
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
        qcustomplot.cpp \
    ../../ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/Layer.cpp \
    ../../ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/Matrix.cpp \
    ../../ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/Network.cpp \
    ../../ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/Neuron.cpp


HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    ../../ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/Layer.h \
    ../../ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/Matrix.h \
    ../../ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/Network.h \
    ../../ArtificialNeuralNetworksProject/Neuron.h \
    qcustomplot.h


FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

How can I find out what the cause is. ?

Comment: Not sure if the Qt build process somehow embeds the path into the build because I had similar problems and only a complete new build resolved it, which is annoying. Doing a clear doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: Did you run qmake on the project after cleaning ?

Comment: by complete new build, do you mean a rebuild in the same project or creating a whole new project and building it?

Comment: @Marco: yes I did , and upon compiling I get the same errors again.

Comment: Apparently your problems are not with Qt but with QCustomPlot lib, you should check very carefully if the path of QCustomPlot libraries is set correctly in your .pro file

Comment: @Marco: I did, I also updated the question with the content of my .pro file. As you see there is nothing wrong with it IMHO.

Comment: You don't link to that library though.

Comment: @Mitch: thats a class, and both the implementation and definition files are included as it is apparent from the .pro file.

Comment: The code it depends on isn't listed under `HEADERS` and `SOURCES` though, so either you need to add it there or link to it with `LIBS`.

Comment: @Mitch: I did as I was instructed by here : http://www.qcustomplot.com/index.php/tutorials/settingup 
And this very same project used to compile, ! I just changed its build directory and now this is the result! I

Comment: Your qcustomplot.cpp seems to have some problems, I suggesto to remove it from project and to add it again.

Comment: @marco: Just did that, still no luck:(

Comment: Sorry no more ideas... I would start over from scratch

Comment: @Marco: Thank you for your time I really appreciate it.
Going to start from scratch!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to get rid of this nerve-racking problem.

First try running qmake, if it didn't help, just delete the `.pro.user` file which resides next to your `.pro` file. After that try to open your project, Just press reconfigure and you are good to go.

In case you got QMake error (qmake is missing or something like that) run qmake first, then you are good to go.